# When did Nguni languages like Zulu adopt capitalisation of proper noun roots?

Tags: orthography, zulu

Motivated by [Is the lowercase first letter of a proper noun common in the Swazi language?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27751/is-the-lowercase-first-letter-of-a-proper-noun-common-in-the-swazi-language)

Zulu, and the other https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nguni_languages as user@6726 reports in his answer there, capitalise the root of proper nouns, and leave their prefixes uncapitalised; this results in camel-case like *isiZulu* and *uDavida*. When and how was this convention introduced?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm building on https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/27752/17064, @user6726's answer to the related question.

The very earliest renderings of Zulu in Roman script, as @user6726 reports, used normal Roman capitalisation conventions. @user6726 reports that

> In Bryant's 1848 article "The Zulu language", citation names are given
>   as e.g. Umpandi, Unyokhana, and Grout 1849 "The Zulu and other
>   dialects of southern Africa" likewise gives Untaba, Ubalekhile.

The [1859 grammar](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=5_MlAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Grammar%20Book%20by%20L.%20Grout&hl=el&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWlNvi2MjaAhUF8WMKHfs2CwwQ6AEILzAB#v=onepage&q=Grammar%20Book%20by%20L.%20Grout&f=false) of Zulu by the American missionary [Lewis Grout](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=Grout%2C%20Lewis%2C%201815%2D1905) likewise still uses the older capitalisation: *Udavida* not *uDavida* for "David":

On the other hand, Bishop [John Colenso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Colenso)'s [grammar written in the same year](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=G61C9mr2ouYC&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) uses the modern camel-case convention. And little hints I see in Wikipedia and Google show that inconsistency in Zulu capitalisation persisted for a while.

What seems to be an explanation occurs in the 1868 book [*Nursery Tales, Traditions, & Histories of the Zulus*](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=C4UBAAAAMAAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=el&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) by [Henry Callaway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_Callaway), which uses the older capitalisation, and rejects camel-case:

> There are two modes of writing—one adopted by Dr. Colenso and Dr.
>   Bleek, in which a number of small words is run together; and the
>   other, that adopted by the American missionaries and others, in which
>   there is, perhaps, the opposite mistake of unnecessary division.
>
> As regards the first, I am quite unable to see anything to recommend
>   it, or even to conceive the reason of its adoption. Why should we
>   write *ngabebabopa*, "they ought to bind them"; and not *nga be ba
>   bopa*, "ought they them bind?" Why should we run the Zulu words
>   together, when we write the English ones apart? (p. ii)
>
> A difficulty, too, has been felt as regards the capital letters; and
>   we find consequently in printed books some ugly anomalies, such as  a
>   capital in the middle of a word, and paragraphs beginning with a small
>   letter. This has arisen apparently, in part, from the error of not
>   regarding the prefix as an essential part of a noun, and so giving the
>   nominal root an undue prominence; and, in part, from our not being
>   accustomed to those *initial* changes upon which grammatical
>   inflection so much depends in the Zulu language. But to use the
>   capital letters to distinguish nominal roots is a novelty in writing
>   (p. iii)

So, Grout wrote Zulu affixes as separate words, Colenso as affixes (something Callaway disagreed with). And (I assume!) Colenso also came up with the camel-case orthography, since he was in effect joining up what Grout had written as two words (*u Davida, n Kosi, isi Zulu*) into single words (*uDavida, nKosi, isiZulu*).